# What is the earliest time in history a non-science fiction movie or TV show is set in?

Tags: realism

I am not talking about science fiction film, more so a realistic representation of PEOPLE living in these old times.

One such example is '10,000 BC' the film. It shows the thinking of people living in such a time (e.g. they are afraid of the river etc.).

Again I don't want to include a film/TV show that is purely science fiction e.g. that a person goes back in time to the big bang or something.

This can however include a film about earlier versions of human beings (e.g. Homo Sapiens) from whom we have descended from. But the representation has to be realistic (ofcourse there is always room for creativity of the director/writer) but no magic or magic kingdoms or things of that nature.

And also no documentaries (although good documentaries would also interest me, however for the sake of this question let's exclude them).

Comment: I'm assuming neither version of 'One Million [Years] BC' has any place in this list... being as nothing vaguely resembling Victor Mature or Raquel Welch was around at that time ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## 80,000BC

[***Quest for Fire***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082484/) (1981)

> The story is set in Paleolithic Europe (**80,000 years ago**), with its plot surrounding the struggle for control of fire by early humans.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quest_for_Fire_(film))</sup>

---

## 16,000BC

[***Clan of the Cave Bear***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090848/) (1986) based on the novel

> The novel references the advance of the polar ice sheets, setting the story before **18,000 years** Before Present (BP), when the farthest southern encroachment of the last glacial period of the current ice age occurred.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Clan_of_the_Cave_Bear)</sup>

---

***Honorable Mentions***

### Dawn of Man (? million years ago)

Ape sequence from [***2001***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062622/) (1968)

> In an African desert millions of years ago, a tribe of hominids is driven away from its water hole by a rival tribe. They awaken to find a featureless black monolith has appeared before them. Influenced by the monolith, they discover how to use a bone as a weapon and drive their rivals away from the water hole.
>
> <sup>[Wikiepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey_(film))</sup>

[image]

---

## 1,000,000BC

[***Missing Link***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095646/) (1988)

> The film is set in Africa roughly one million years ago, at a time when one species of "man-apes" (Australopithecus robustus) was being displaced by the ancestors of modern humans. These ancestors are possibly Homo erectus, but they are never named in the film. They are only addressed as "man" and from the few scenes where they show any visibility, they vaguely resemble modern humans.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_Link_(film))</sup>

Comment: The first segment of 2001 might be worth adding to that list; even though it's sci-fi, up until the appearance of the monolith, it's 'pure' cro-magnon man.

Comment: @Tetsujin I thought of that one but there's no timeframe (although) one could be guessed at but it's more apes than "man". Added as "honorable mention".

Comment: It does show the transition from herbivore to omnivore/carnivore, which I guess is going to be closest to an actual 'clue'.